# PHP strtotime using m-d-Y format

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have my dates in format (m-d-Y)  month-day-Year. I'm trying to subtract dates. I can't use strtotime() because it won't work in that format. How can I subtract dates with m-d-Y format?

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

  $olddate = "11-04-2013"; 
  $today = date("m-d-Y");

  $days = $olddate - $today;

  echo $days;

?>
```

If I use strtotime, my result (as of 11-05-2013) is "30". But I can't just divide by 30. If I change the olddate to "10-04-2013", then the result is also "30".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use php's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class (php 5.3+ for `createFromFormat`):

```
$olddate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '11-04-2013');    // for example, see manual for formats
$today = new DateTime();

$diff = $today->diff($olddate);
$diff_string = $diff->format('%a days');
```

Comment: if i echo $diff, I get an error that the DateInterval could not be converted to a string. How do I echo the result?

Comment: @bagofmilk Check the manual on `format`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php, see my edit

Comment: I see you edited your answer. This is a great start but unfortunately this doesn't work if the olddate is changed to 10-04-2013. The result is still 1 day.

Comment: @bagofmilk That's true, because the month got increased as well. If you want the total number of days, you need `a` instead of `d`, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime::createFromFormat to get the timestamp and then get the difference.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

DateTime class, or you use `str_replace()` - with / it should work fine with `strtotime()`.  That is a common US date format order but the separators are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this:

```
$oldDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', "11-04-2013");
$today = new \DateTime('today');

$difference = $today->diff($oldDate);
echo $difference->format('%a');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare the difference between two date:
convert string to dateformat by

```
new DateTime("11-04-2013") or new DateTime(date("m-d-Y"))

$diffe = new DateTime("11-04-2013")->diff(new DateTime(date("m-d-Y")));
echo $diffe->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Just replace the characters. You can get how many days since a date in a procedural way like this:

```
$date = '11-04-2013';
$time = strtotime(str_replace('-','/',$date));
$now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$diff = $now - $time;
$days = $diff / (24 * 60 * 60);
echo $days;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could look into this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Example #1 DateTime::diff() example

### Object oriented style

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

### Procedural style

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

The above examples will output:

```
+2 days
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with the format Month-day-Year, otherwise i would use strototime().

Comment: What if you changed the "-" into "/", or did explode('-', $date)?